# How do I access the user calls to mobile?

Tags: android

I want my application to be activated when the user make a specific call. Is there any way to take information which call is making by user in the same  time ( not afterwords ) in order to activate the app at the right time ?

Ok i wrote this code for my case and it works:

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

                if(null == bundle) return;

                String phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

                if( phonenumber.equals("11111111") ) {

                    Intent myactivity = new Intent(context, MyKeyboard.class);
                    myactivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(myactivity);

                }

        }

}
```

In the Manifest i add this:

```
<receiver 
            android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"> 
                   <intent-filter> 
                      <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
                   </intent-filter> 
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

Comment: This can be done in two ways and is relatively easy to implement, however since you are not clear in what you actually want to do it's impossible to provide an accurate answer. You can register one of your activities to be called when the call intent is raised or you can create a broadcast receiver that will listen for the intent and get the phone number from that, however your app needs to be already running for the second approach to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used broadcast receiver as you can see but i am not sure if the way is right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know, but I think that's a really dangerous practice. It all depends on what you intend to do with your app. If it's a recording app, I think you can't even think of developping it, or don't post on the internet about it because it would be illegal in many countries. That's how I see and how I feel your question. About Android there is not 15k places to search, have a look at the android API.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html

This, for example, I don't know if it's a real time log, or if it's filled after the call is terminated. But you can search in that direction.